# detect finding patterns in qrcode using matlab

Tags: qr-code

I am encoding a **qr code** in **matlab** using **zxing** paths. The encoded qr code is saved as jpg image. Then, it's finder patterns i.e the three squares are being detevted using centroid,area and bounding regions and one square is then colored with red color with red as background too. Now such three codes are being made and added together to form a single colored code. 
Now, the region which I am detecting is not being detected properly due to which while decoding steps problem is being created.

Comment: please show what you have done so far.

Comment: You use 3 different colors (RGB) to create 3 qr codes an then overlap them?  Can you clarify this?

Comment: i encoded three different QR code containing messages "hello", "what", "how" using Zxing, an open source and MAT LAB.

After encoding these three codes were saved as .jpg image and the finder patterns (ie. the three square boxes) were identified using MAT LAB. then top left square of image1 and its background was changed to colored red color, lower left sqaure and background of image 2 to blue and upper right square and background to green in MAT LAB using centroid,area and bounding box properties. they were saved as jpg image.

Comment: After that these three individual codes were added up to form a single RGB colored QR code. Then these three images were added to form a single image of qr code.

the problem is when i am trying to decode it, by removing layers of colors one by one (ie by making R and G as zero) for 1st time and (G and B) to zero second time. the pixels are not turning to zero of the colored image and i am not able to decode it. Kindly tell where the problem is arising. i think the square patterns are not getting recognized properly

Comment: please give your email id, ill send the code and images i am using.